# Puppet doesn't recognize the resource type "gauth_credential"

Tags: cloud, puppet

I was trying to create a Google Cloud Platform instance. I installed Puppet the google cloud module and the required gems with the command - **sudo /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/gem install googleauth google-api-client**. 
All the modules are installed and the puppet gems - [screenshot of the module list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Nt5.png), but still when I try to execute my .pp file there's and error saying:

**Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Unknown resource type: 'gauth_credential' (file: /home/stiefff/puppet/auth.pp, line: 14, column: 1) on node stiefff-b5400**

Can somebody help me resolve this?